# Problems migrating from XCode 3.2.2 to 3.2.3

Tags: xcode, upgrade, incompatibility

After upgrading my copy of xcode from 3.2.2 to 3.2.3, I am getting over 10000 compilation errors. I have switched all frameworks to the iOS 4.0.x versions, and have set the new sdk to 4.0, with iOS 3.1 as compilation target. What could be causing 10000 errors, and how do I resolve them? (These errors appear everywhere, and even in sdk files and system headers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, without knowing what those errors are, it is difficult to say.

I might suggest uninstalling Xcode 3.2.3 and installing the latest version which is 3.2.5.

To uninstall properly, you need to enter:

> sudo (xcode
>   folder)/Library/uninstall-devtools
>   --mode=all

in the terminal and then install 3.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deleting and recompiling the project using a new compilation target. Turns out some of the project settings in xcode can be rather funky, and will cause GCC to mistake objective c code as plain c code.